# Drupal 7 - Adding a cycle of images on each page

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

Im fairly new to developing in Drupal, i am using the 7.x code.

I have a site that i need to develop, which has a cycle of images on each page.

I am usually a wordpress developer, and how i achieve it there is a gallery plugin, then insert the shortcode on each page.

Is there something like this in Drupal, or could someone suggest something similar that i could use?

Cheers,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drupal 7 is a bit shaky at this stage, so some of the module I listed here might not be suitable for production environment.

-Gallery Formatter

-Colorbox

are the two modules that do the trick for me. Search in drupal official site

To make gallery appear on all page, You can load the gallery in the block.

Comment: Hey thanks for this, i have installed the Gallery Formatter plugin, it seems to be the one i need, except it seems to add the images to the content tag ... Is there any way i can seperate the content from the images, as my template displays images up the top and the main content down the bottom ... i added the gallery to the page content type if that helps

Comment: for basic layout change, you can use the manage display option, change the weight of the gallery so it appears before the content on the page, to separate, you will need to use the blocks or even panels, some info here http://drupal.org/documentation/modules/block

Answer (score 0):

You could create the site at drupalgardens.com and see how they do it. They offer the required functionality or if you are just starting you could start there and export the site later to run it on your own server.

Answer (score 0):

It took me a while to figure the right search query fot this myself, but I think what you are searching for is called a **carousel**.

Just browse the [Drupal Module search](http://drupal.org/project/modules?filters=drupal_core%3A103%20bs_project_sandbox%3A0&solrsort=sis_project_release_usage%20desc&text=carousel) of the keywords *carousel*.

I found the first one [jCarousel](http://drupal.org/project/jcarousel) doing exacly what I wanted, when combined with the [Views Module](http://drupal.org/project/views).

Sometimes it's called a **rotator** or **slider** and additionally you could check out this Drupal [comparison page](http://drupal.org/node/418616)